# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception because of camerawesome package

Tags: flutter, camera

I am using [camerawesome: ^1.3.1](https://pub.dev/packages/camerawesome) package. My Flutter version is 3.7.8. When I try to run my app from the Android Studio, it gives me this build failed error. Please help me solve this.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'C:\Users\ibrahim.hossen\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\camerawesome-1.4.0\android\build.gradle'
>   line: 74
> - What went wrong: Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\ibrahim.hossen\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\camerawesome-1.4.0\android\build.gradle'.
>
> > startup failed:   build file 'C:\Users\ibrahim.hossen\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\camerawesome-1.4.0\android\build.gradle':
> > 74: unexpected token: && @ line 74, column 13.
> > && isWithinRange(getMinor(tabVersion), getMinor(tabMin), getMinor(tabMax))
> > ^
>
> 1 error
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1

**Here is my flutter doctor:**

> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
>
> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.19044.2728], locale en-US)
>
> [√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or
> higher)
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 32.0.0)
>
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
>
> [!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019
> 16.11.18)
> X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++"
> workload, and include these components:
> MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
> - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
> C++ CMake tools for Windows
> Windows 10 SDK
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
>
> [√] Connected device (4 available)
>
> [√] HTTP Host Availability
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: Have you tried updating Gradle?

Comment: Also suggest using the latest version, I just checked, they have updated their version just 2 hours back.

Comment: Thanks, @NiladriRaychaudhuri for reminding me to update my Gradle. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your gradle to the latest version should fix this